# magento 2 corresponding layout xml file

Tags: magento2, module, layout, blocks

How to write the **equivalent layout xml file in magento 2**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <merchandisingpage_index_index translate="label">
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="setTitle">
         <title>Merchandising</title>
      </action>
    </reference>

 <reference name="root">
  <action method="setTemplate">
      <template>page/3columns.phtml</template>
  </action>
</reference>

<reference name="left">
  <block type="merchandisingpage/filter" name="custom_filter" before="-"/>
</reference>

<reference name="content">
  <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">

   <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="tagalys_toolbar/toolbar.phtml">

    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
    </block>

    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
      <name>product_list_toolbar</name>
    </action>

  </block>
</reference>
</merchandisingpage_index_index>
```

Comment: refer http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Magento 2 has quite a lot of differences with Magento 1, **providing an equivalence of a layout XML file will not necessarily reproduce the same behavior as the equivalent file in Magento 1.**

However, I'm *assuming here that you've taken that into consideration and that you are willing to spend some time debugging and investigating time in the module you're trying to convert to Magento 2.*

Thus, the equivalence of this file would be a file called `merchandising_index_index.xml` under `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <referenceContainer name="left">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Merchandising\Filter" name="custom_filter" />
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
             </block>
             <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                 <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
             </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Please note that you will have to make sure that the block that corresponds to `merchandising/filter` in your original layout file is located under `Vendor/Module/Block/Merchandising/Filter`

Comment: Hi Raphael, in magento 1.8 Filter.php is in Vendor/Module/Block/Filter.php and in my magento2 layout file i have used <referenceContainer name="left">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Filter" name="custom_filter" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>   is tat correct?

Comment: @SachinS yes it sounds correct

Comment: ok, i have a doubt in the content tag as to why blocktype 'catalog/product_list_toolbar' and 'page/html_page' is split into blockClass. Could you pls explain

Comment: @SachinS toolbar and pager are split in Magento 2 that's why ;)